# Select substring up until second underscore in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have strings like this:

```
FOO_BAR_3423423_dsadsa.doc
BAZ_BAZzz_dsadsa.nox
```

The number if `_` can differ, but I need to select always up untill the second `_`:

```
FOO_BAR
BAZzz_BAZ
```

I am able to select until the first `_`:

```
SUBSTRING ([COLUMN], 0, CHARINDEX('/', [COLUMN], 0))
```

But how to expand this to go up to the second underscore?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Cross Apply` the following query will give you the indexes with the data.

```
declare @T table
(
  Name_Level varchar(25)
)

insert into @T values
('FOO_BAR_3423423_dsadsa'),
('BAZ_BAZzz_dsadsa'),

select SUBSTRING(Name_Level,0,p2.pos) As Data,p1.Pos as firstOccurance,p2.pos As secondOccurance
from @T
  cross apply (select (charindex('_', Name_Level))) as P1(Pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex('_', Name_Level, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
```

Result:

```
-------------------------
FOO_BAR     4   8
BAZ_BAZzz   4   10
```

If you want to get the next index just add one more `CrossApply` and it will give you the next index of `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SUBSTRING ([COLUMN], 0, CHARINDEX('/', [COLUMN], CHARINDEX('/', [COLUMN], 0) + 1))
```

This won't work if there is less than two though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `while loop`. Try this.

```
DECLARE @str    VARCHAR(5000)='FOO_BAR_3423423_dsadsa.doc',
        @temp   INT=1,
        @cnt    INT=0,
        @result VARCHAR(5000)='',
        @intr   VARCHAR(50)=''

WHILE @temp <= Len(@str)
  BEGIN
      SELECT @intr = Substring(@str, @temp, 1)
      SET @cnt += (SELECT CASE WHEN @intr = '_' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      SET @result+=@intr
      IF @cnt = 2
        BREAK
      SET @temp+=1
  END

SELECT SELECT left(@result ,len(@result)-1)
```